# How can we show that it is perpendicular to the tangent plane?

Tags: differential-geometry

We consider the surface $S$ defined by $f(x, y, z) = 0$, where $f$ is a smooth function such that $\nabla f$ does not vanish at any point of $S$.

How can we show that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane at every point of $S$, and deduce that $S$ is orientable?

Comment: How do you define the tangent plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec R(t)$ represent an arbitrary parametric curve on the surface defined by $f(\vec r)=0$.

Then, note that $g(t)=f(\vec R(t))=0$ implies that $g'(t)=0$.  From the chain rule we have

$$g'(t)=\nabla f(\vec R(t))\cdot \vec R\,'(t)=0 \tag 1$$

Since $\vec R\,'(t)$ is an arbitrary tangent to the surface, we conclude that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to all tangent curves and therefore is perpendicular to the surface $f=0$.

Comment: So $\overrightarrow{R}(t)$ is an arbitrary curve on the surface $S$, right? $$$$ Is the domain of $f$ the set of curves?

Comment: @marystar For the first question, yes. I don't understand your second one.

Comment: Why can we take $f(\overrightarrow{R}(t))$ ? You say that the surface is defined by $f(\overrightarrow{r})=0$. What is $\overrightarrow{r}$ ? A curve?

Comment: @marystar $\vec r$ is vector notation for the $(x,y,z)$.  And $t\mapsto \vec R(t)$ is a curve, described parametrically, on the surface defined by $f(x,y,z)=0$. So,

Comment: I see... $$$$ We get $$g'(t)=\nabla f(\vec R(t))\cdot \vec R\,'(t)$$ where $R(t)=(R_1(t), R_2(t), R_3(t))$ as follows $$g'(t)=(f(\overrightarrow{R}(t)))'=f_x(\overrightarrow{R}(t))\cdot R_1'(t)+f_y(\overrightarrow{R}(t))\cdot R_2'(t)+ f_z(\overrightarrow{R}(t))\cdot R_3'(t) \\ =\nabla f(\vec R(t))\cdot \vec R\,'(t)$$ right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes.  Well done!  You have it now.

Comment: How can we deduce that $S$ is orientable?

Comment: $f$ is smooth and $\nabla f$ is never zero.

Comment: In my book there is the following definition: $$$$ A surface $S$ is orientable if there exists an atlas $A$ for $S$ with the property
that, if $\Phi$ is the transition map between any two surface patches in $A$, then $\det (J(\Phi)) > 0$ where $\Phi$ is defined. $$$$ ($J(\Phi)$ is the Jacobian matrix of the transition map $\Phi$) $$$$ Is this equivalent to $f$ smooth and $\nabla f$ never zero?

Comment: Perhaps you can show that if $f$ is smooth with non-vanishing derivative, then the surface defined by $f=0$ satisfies that definition.

Comment: Now I found also the following part at the book: $$$$ An oriented surface is a surface $S$ together with a smooth choice of unit
normal $N$ at each point.  Any oriented surface is orientable! $$$$ Can we maybe use this? We have shown that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane at every point of $S$, this means that when we normalize $\nabla f$, i.e., $\frac{\nabla f}{\|\nabla f\|}$, we have a smooth unit normal at each point. Or is this wrong?

Comment: Yes.  That should do it.  Of course, you tacitly used the fact that is never vanishes.  Do you see where?

Comment: When we normalize $\nabla f$, right?

Comment: We have shown that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane at every point of $S$. Does this mean that it is perpendicular to $S$ ?

Comment: Yes.  It is normal to $S$

Comment: Does it always stand that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the surface that is defined by $f=0$, or is it in this case so because we have shown that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the tangent plane of $S$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $x\in S$, then the tangent space of $S$ at $x$ can be seen as the space of velocity vectors at $x$ of smooth curves (passing through $x$, of course). So let $\gamma:I\to S$ be a smooth curve. Can you show that $\langle\dot{\gamma},\nabla f\rangle = 0$?